# Postgresql create generated column syntax error, why?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, generated-columns

I have a postgres table with two columns (an identificator and a date) that are a composite primary key. I would like to hash the concatenation in another column, generating this value everytime a new record is inserted. For that I'm trying to alter my table in order to create a generated column:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN hash_id_date VARCHAR(50)
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MD5(my_table.original_id||'-'||my_table.time))
STORED;
```

This raises me the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 4: GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MD5(my_table.original_id,'-',my_table.t...
                            ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 178
```

I'm turning into madness to find where is the syntax error... I've read about `STABLE` and `IMMUTABLE` functions and generated columns should always have an `IMMUTABLE` function as expression. As far as I know `MD5` is `IMMUTABLE` but the error message is not even capable to reach that level.

Any help?

Comment: I would try removing an element from the calculated clause one by one in order to find out what causing it - for example, try AS ((my_table.original_id||'-'||my_table.time)) without MD5, try without concat, etc...

Comment: What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: Yep, @a_horse_with_no_name, your suspicions were right. My current version is not supporting generated column. I'm currently creating a new column and trying to simulate it with a trigger, however my current rows are not affected by this. I'm trying to update my table with the values of each row.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's exactly what I ran into. Local ran fine since it's Postgres v12, my deployed environment was v10.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the basic functionality for calculating the MD5 is common you can create a function for the calculation. Use this function wherever it's needed, including updating your current rows and invoke from a trigger on yo your table. If the particular MD5 calculation is not all that common you can just put the calculation in the trigger function and also use it in a independent update for current rows. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7b47dd02b504a9b96d83d7f3b749f3a8) for example with assumption it is common in your app.